# Generate multiple apks from one project without including libs

Tags: android, gradle, polymer

I develop an Android application and using webview in it. I do not face any problems with legacy Android browser on Android 4.4.3 and over. In order to support lower versions on Android, I have to use Crosswalk and I successfully integrated in by following the guide below: 
(https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/webview.html)

When I put Crosswalk in my application, it adds a 20mb overhead to my project which I try to get rid of. So my plan is to generate two different apks. One is with Crosswalk and one is not. The thing is; I do not want to create two seperate projects.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

**My question is:**

Since Crossswalk has its own libraries need to included, my first apk (which needs to be compiled without Crosswalk) contains these unnecessary libraries. I want to continue my development with one project but want to create two seperate apks by only making some changes or defining some rules in gradle, etc. Is this possible?

**Output:**

Same Project -> Without Crosswalk -> Wtihout Libraries -> APK (small size) (same package name but different versionCode)

Same Project -> With Crosswalk -> With Libraries Included -> APK (large size) (same package name but different versionCode)

Comment: You can create two different modules in Android Studio. In one, include the CrossWalk library as a dependency and don't include it in the other. Since you plan to release two different APK's, they (_the two modules_) would need different package names. And because of the way a project structure is created in Android Studio, you can have just a single project and yet have the option of generating multiple APK's (_by creating multiple modules_).